# AZURE SAML / MS AD dual SSO integration with Wildfly

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, wildfly

I was searching for a while for an answer or a documentation without success for the following,

could we configure  wildfly 20+ with two SSO providers? for example primary with MS AD and secodary as cloud SAML Azure? is this setup feasible?

Any one has experience with this configuration an has documentation or online ref for that?

i ve tried to check in jboss official doc, but it seems nothing about this is there.

Comment: What would the user experience be in this case?  I try to log into your application and I'm asked for my credentials.  That is checked and, if it doesn't succeed I'm redirected to *another* login?  Wildfly can easily verify a token from any where you want.  But what flow do you expect?

Comment: in case of 'primary' SSO failure ( network issue, down ...) I'll be redirected to the 'secondary' one.